# How Adagrad optimizer work in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

1. According to the initial paper, there should be a parameter named δ. But I can't find such argument in TensorFlow *AdagradOptimizer* construtor.
2. There is an argument  named *initial_accumulator_value*, it is suggested to set as 0, but TensorFlow uses 0.1 as default. It is proper for me to set it as 0?

Thank you so much for your time!

Garrett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initial_accumulator_value` is indeed the \delta and it should not be initialized to `0`. A value of `0.01` is more appropriate but the default of `0.1` is fine.

Btw, if you are in the business of playing with optimizers, authors of Adagrad have a new optimizer https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.09568 that performs considerably better than existing ones. It's TF implementation should be released fairly soon, Q2 2018.

Comment: Hi iga, thanks for the information. But I still don't get it. I have learned that initial gradient accumulation vector should be initialized to 0. And \delta should be initialized to a tiny number.  And I actually found that [this chapter](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=80glDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=tensorflow+adagrad+%CE%B4&source=bl&ots=vdooNjp045&sig=WH_9hoXkPPevKtvrgqvklbAdKvk&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=tensorflow%20adagrad%20%CE%B4&f=false) says that \delta and initial gradient accumulation vector are rolled into `initial_accumulator_value` in TensorFlow implementation.

Comment: Is it the same if I initialize `initial_accumulator_value` to a tiny number?

Comment: I am not sure. You can check the code: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/72239e9b0432a26feadc2412abf89a8fb92828f0/tensorflow/core/kernels/training_ops.cc#L152. `accum` is the initial_accumulator_value. You can see it being passed down as is in here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c7a04561fb8972fb64907acc5f10f3c6d4cef9f2/tensorflow/python/training/adagrad.py#L69

Comment: Thanks for posting about that new optimizer. I've been experimenting with it, very preliminary but seems very promising. Are there any other reviews/testimonials about the shampoo optimizer? Can't seem to find too many people using it

Comment: I am sure some researchers are using it but don't know of any large systematic comparison. It should be fairly easy to just try it on your model and see how it performs.